# Find Contains Word and Copy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to copy sentence like this with jquery

```
<div id="a">This is my car and this is my house</div>
```

then display to this div

```
<div id="car"></div> <div id="house"></div>
```

Result

```
<div id="car">This is my car</div> <div id="house">this is my house</div>
```

Comment: Good luck with your endeavors.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Maybe your brother Mark can help you.

Comment: You're a zuckerberg and you're asking for help :/ pretty funny aint it? However, use split for the job! Its gonna do the work, as you want the paragraph to be splitted at '`' and `'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var divArry = $("#a").text().split(' and ');
$("#car").text(divArry[0]);
$("#house").text(divArry[1]);
```

This will use `and` as the separator for the array.  But if there are more `and` within the text, this logic will fail.

Comment: Awesome,this is working with split,thanks

Comment: thats pretty backwards, im not saying theres a easier way, but it is a hack, and wont work in the long run - as you yourself pointed out.

Comment: Actually the question was somehow lame, he must have provided more then one inputs and then worked on that data.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight - The question is straight-forward, this is not meant to be code for endurance, I believe it is just very specific for what is needed at that time, although it is not very good practice to do this with strings that can contain different types of content, but this was the only example string that was provided.

Comment: i didnt `-1` i just mentioned that it isnt reusable and therefore isnt the best solution